# I there a good ruby book for learning sockets programming?

Tags: c, ruby, sockets, unix, socket.io

Is there a good book for ruby sockets programming or we have to rely on Unix C books for theory and source ?.

Comment: Not that I know. The API (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/socket/rdoc/classes/Socket.html) is pretty good, Programming Ruby online (http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) has a small chapter to sockets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the goal is to learn socket programming I would recommend using C and reading through some Unix system programming books. The books will probably be much better and go into more detail than a sockets book that is Ruby specific (mainly because C, Unix and sockets have been around much longer than Ruby and my quick Googling didn't find a Ruby specific book).

Books I would recommend:

- [Unix Systems Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130424110)
- [Unix Network Programming Volume 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551)

After getting a handle on the sockets in general (even if you don't write any C) the [Ruby API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/socket/rdoc/classes/Socket.html) for sockets will make much more sense.

Comment: In my experience that is true for all languages, even Java. Read the C documentation, then go to the language of choice. (Read the Winsock FAQ: http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/ if you are on Windows.)